# Can systemd's .mount units be used to mount to points within a service's namespace only?

Tags: mount, systemd, namespaces

I am interested in setting a temporary directory that exists for the duration of the `.service` unit's running - exactly like the `PrivateTmp=` directive but on a custom mount point specified by a systemd `.mount` unit. Is this possible? Or should I be mounting to the mount point via a `ExecStartPre=` directive within the service file itself?